# Am i considered "associated" to a company i have quit but still own stock in?

Tags: united-states, day-trading

I quit an equity trading broker at the beginning of this month.  I still own stock in the company.  Am i still considered to be "associated" to this company?  I am asking because i went to open an account online at another broker and their application asked if "any member of your immediate family living in the same household, including parents, in-laws, siblings, and dependents is licensed, employed by, or associated with, a broker-dealer firm, a financial services regulator, securities exchange, or member of a securities exchange."
I don't see myself as associated because i own something in the company.  The company i worked for isn't going to share anything with me because i don't work there anymore.  I just receive a dividend check every month.

Answer (score 1):

No. You are not "associated" just by owning stock.

From [United States Security Exchange Commission - Guide to Broker-Dealer Registration document](https://www.sec.gov/reportspubs/investor-publications/divisionsmarketregbdguidehtm.html)

> **II. WHO IS REQUIRED TO REGISTER - D. 1. "Associated Persons" of a Broker-Dealer**
>
> We call individuals who work for a registered broker-dealer "associated persons." This is the case whether such individuals are employees, independent contractors, or are otherwise working with a broker-dealer. These individuals may also be called "stock brokers" or "registered representatives."

As you no longer work for your old company and have no business relationship you are no longer an "associated person". The application requirement is probably related to reporting requirements as trading accounts by employees of a broker-dealer need to be monitored.

Any new employee of broker-dealer needs to declare their non-company accounts held by third-parties. Those third-parties will send statements/transactions to the employer's compliance department until those assets are rolled over into the employer's brokerage system or get agreement on monitoring transactions.